# What is the difference between "return" and "yield"?

Tags: word-request, word-comparison, modern-life, technology

In the Python programming language, "yield" and "return" are keywords with specific meanings.

A function can either *yield* a result (sending that result back and then continuing to work), or *return* it (sending the result back and then being done). So for example, a function to find prime numbers might *yield* each one as it found it, while a procedure to multiply numbers together would just *return* the product once the calculation was finished.

How would one best express this distinction in Latin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about *redde* for "return" and *ede* for "yield"?
These keywords are orders ("do so and so"), and therefore I find imperatives most natural.

The verb *reddere* means giving back, and I think that captures the idea of "return" pretty well.
One might also consider the simple *da*, but that would bring it closer to giving than returning.
Whether a value is returned or not, a function returns also the thread of execution, so I think *redde* is better than *da*.
I assume that the keyword "return" is read as "give back" instead of "go back"; the latter would only make sense for some uses of the keyword, so giving is probably a better interpretation.

On the other hand, *edere* means giving out, which is reasonably close to yielding.
It sounds sensible to me for a function to either give back once or keep giving out repeatedly.
I also find it convenient that similar things are expressed with the same verb with a different prefix.